# How to hide/archive a Property and/or View from the Google Analytics UI

Tags: google-analytics

I have many Properties for sites that do not exist anymore. I have many Views which may have old filters or otherwise aren't the View I use day-to-day. I don't want to delete these because they contain historical data. I just don't want to see them in the long list of Views. Better yet, I'd like to hide them at an account level so that other administrators don't see old/bad Views by default.

You can delete a Google Analytics Property or View (steps: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1042032?hl=en or https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009621?hl=en), but can you *hide* a Property and/or View?

You can also Star Views. This is the closest there is, but Stars could be used for different reasons and don't have global UI implications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not (currently) possible to archive or hide views or properties.